# how to get Package name of app with broadcast receiver in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am trying to get the package name of an app that the user is attempting to uninstall, but the following code only gives me the package name of the current running activity:

```java
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Package ::" + componentInfo.getPackageName());
```

Could someone please help me figure out how to get the package name of the specific app that the user is trying to uninstall?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want the package name of your application or other application

Comment: any application on which user clicks

Answer (score 1):

- Create receiver for

  `<receiver
          android:name=".PackageReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"/>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
              <data android:scheme="package"/>
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>`
- In OnReceive()
  get action by`intent.getAction()`
  get package by `intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart()`

Answer (score 0):

The package names is there in Intent you got from BroadcasReceiver, use the "getData()" function, there is the `ComponentName` of the installed/uninstalled package.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get `ComponentName` in the way you are getting. After that get ApplicationInfo instance

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(componentName.getPackageName(), 0);
```

Now get package name as appInfo.packageName.
[check here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#packageName)

Comment: getting error here    ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(componentInfo.getPackageName(), 0);

Comment: giving the current running activity's package name:| i want app's name

Comment: Your question was to get package name

Comment: yes package name of that application on which user clicks